# "Received no data in response" while using unity web requests

Tags: c#, php, unity-game-engine, web-hosting, unitywebrequest

i am using this script to read data from a php script i hosted online using my php.
when i run my game i am getting a 'Received no data in response' message and runtime error that says :'Curl error 52: Empty reply from server' in the console .

```
    public IEnumerator connect( )
    {
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get("https://lazyboy.wuaze.com/connect.php"))
        {

            yield return www.SendWebRequest();
            if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
            {
                print(www.error);
            }
            else
            {
                print(www.downloadHandler.text);
                byte[] results = www.downloadHandler.data;

            }
        }
    }
```

my php script:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$servername = '';
$username = '';
$password = '';
$dbname = '';
// Create connection

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
else{
    echo"connected to DB";
}
?>
```

i tried going to my URL and it displays "connected to DB"

Comment: well you arent using form, so thats just erronous.  one thing that is obvious is it takes ages for the connected to come up.. i wonder if somehow it thought it was done

Comment: PS my unix box says yes.`--2023-11-10 13:26:36--  (try: 3)  https://lazyboy.wuaze.com/connect.php
Connecting to lazyboy.wuaze.com (lazyboy.wuaze.com)|185.27.134.33|:443... connected.
WARNING: The certificate of ‘lazyboy.wuaze.com’ is not trusted.
WARNING: The certificate of ‘lazyboy.wuaze.com’ doesn't have a known issuer.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... No data received.
Retrying.`

it isnt getting anything so abandoned ship

Comment: so, what should i do?